# Meteor throwing error when trying to use bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteorite

So I am trying to display all the registered users as tabs(that you can close) on top of the home page. For this I am trying to recycle code in this jisfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4atm5abf/. However, I am running into errors/issues when trying to use bootstrap.

Here is what my header.html looks like:

```html
<template name="header">
    <header class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="{{pathFor 'userSearch'}}">SocialStore</a>
            {{> listUsers}}
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li>{{>loginButtons}}</li>
                    <!-- <li>{{>user_tab}}</li> -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>

<template name="listUsers">
    <div class="container-fluid ">
        {{script}}
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs marginBottom" id="myTab">
            {{#each Allusers}}
            <li><a href="#profile"><button class="close closeTab" type="button" >×</button>{{username}}</a></li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is what my header.js looks like:

```js
Template.listUsers.helpers({
    Allusers: function() {
        return Meteor.users.find().fetch();
    },

    script: function() { 
    var currentTab;
    var composeCount = 0;
    //initilize tabs
    $(function () {
        //when ever any tab is clicked this method will be call
        $("#myTab").on("click", "a", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).tab('show');
            $currentTab = $(this);
        });

        registerCloseEvent();
    });

    function registerCloseEvent() {

        $(".closeTab").click(function () {
            //there are multiple elements which has .closeTab icon so close the tab whose close icon is clicked
            var tabContentId = $(this).parent().attr("href");
            $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //remove li of tab
            $('#myTab a:last').tab('show'); // Select first tab
            $(tabContentId).remove(); //remove respective tab content
        });
    }

    //shows the tab with passed content div id..paramter tabid indicates the div where the content resides
    function showTab(tabId) {
        $('#myTab a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
    }
    //return current active tab
    function getCurrentTab() {
        return currentTab;
    }

    //this will return element from current tab
    //example : if there are two tabs having  textarea with same id or same class name then when $("#someId") whill return both the text area from both tabs
    //to take care this situation we need get the element from current tab.
    function getElement(selector) {
        var tabContentId = $currentTab.attr("href");
        return $("" + tabContentId).find("" + selector);
    }

    function removeCurrentTab() {
        var tabContentId = $currentTab.attr("href");
        $currentTab.parent().remove(); //remove li of tab
        $('#myTab a:last').tab('show'); // Select first tab
        $(tabContentId).remove(); //remove respective tab content
    }
}})
```

This is what my package file looks like:

```
Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

insecure
standard-app-packages
iron:router
accounts-base
accounts-password
autopublish
accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown
jquery
```

I removed bootstrap from the packages and added bootsrap-combined.min.css to /client/stylesheets and bootstrap.min.js to lib/ These are the two files that the example in the jsfiddle uses.

Here is the error that I get:

```
=> Modified -- restarting.
W20141105-20:56:59.640(-8)? (STDERR) 
W20141105-20:56:59.642(-8)? (STDERR) /home/shubham/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.m1x0kw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141105-20:56:59.643(-8)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20141105-20:56:59.643(-8)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20141105-20:56:59.644(-8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20141105-20:56:59.644(-8)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/bootstrap.min.js:6:451
W20141105-20:56:59.644(-8)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/bootstrap.min.js:8:3
W20141105-20:56:59.645(-8)? (STDERR)     at /home/shubham/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141105-20:56:59.645(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141105-20:56:59.645(-8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/shubham/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.m1x0kw++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141105-20:56:59.646(-8)? (STDERR)     at /home/shubham/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
[=================== ] 95% 31.7s
```

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to make this work. Thanks

Comment: Bootstrap v2.2.2! Jesus that's outdated! At least use 2.3.2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried grabbing bootstrap.js from a CDN and including:

in whatever html file you have your  defined in?

That way you can tell if it's an interaction between bootstrap and meteor or whether your file organization is the issue (not sure if it works to be putting bootstrap.js in your lib folder or how exactly you are including it into your html)